# Android Billing Order Id

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have a question about the Android Billing
When the user bought our inapp product, i will sent the Google response JSON to our server, and i found there are two kind of order id, one is begin with GPA,and i can find the order id from the Google Console, and the other kind of order id is like this

> (2171707929630395169.3174492821760928)->but I can't find this id from the Google Console.

and the Google response JSON's format is as same as the order id which begin with GPA. So has anyone faced this problem too?

Please tell me the reason.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a hacked purchase. Since you don't get paid for it, assume the user never bought it anyway.